# jQuery DataTables - Replace/Update row using jQuery object. Or fnUpdate

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm successfully able to add a row to the datatable using the following code:

works:

```
var serversTable = $('#datatable-table').dataTable().api();

var serverRowTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#serverRowTemplate').html());

var $row = $(serverRowTemplate(data.results[r]));

serversTable.row.add($row).draw(false);
```

But when I try to update(replace) a row using a similar method, I have no luck. I've also tried using fnUpdate, but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to basically replace/update an existing row via a jQuery object. Here is the code that fails to update the table:

doesn't work:

```
var serversTable = $('#datatable-table').dataTable().api();

var oldRow = $('#dashboardTemplateContainer tr[data-tag="'+ data.results[r].tag + '"]'); // select the row i'm looking for

var serverRowTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#serverRowTemplate').html()); //compiles the handlebars template. i need this template as i have a lot of conditionals etc. 

var $row = $(serverRowTemplate(data.results[r])); // turning the template into a jQuery object worked for the row.add() function in the above example.

serversTable.rows(oldRow).data($row).draw(false); // replace the old row with the new row. doesn't work.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

API method [`rows().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.data%28%29) can only be used to retrieve the data. Use [`row().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) instead to set data for a row.

However you won't be able to use jQuery object for `<TR>` node to update the row's data. Probably your best bet in this case would be to remove the row with [`row().remove()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29) and re-add it if all you have is `<TR>` node.

Comment: but how would I had it on the same position?

Comment: @RohitKhatri, position will depend on the currently sorted column. Even if you use `row().data()` position will change if the data changes in the column the table is being sorted on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax in your handler and update event follow steps below:

1. First get a refrence to `tr` before success callback
2. Then, in your response, append a `AllColumnsData` object and fill it with
   updated data.

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
    var tid = $(this).data("tid");
    var currentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/data/get/?tid=" + tid,
        success: function (data) {
            dt1.row(currentTR).data(data.Data3); 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-new').on('click',function(){
        var rData = [
            test1,
            test2,
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
         $('#dataTable').DataTable().row.add(rData).draw(false);
    });

   $('#dataTable').on('click', '.update', function () {
        var pageParamTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
        var rData = [
            test1,
            test2,
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="' + response.result[0].id + '" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
        pageParamTable
                .row( tableRow )
                .data(rData)
                .draw();
    });
    $('#dataTable').on('click', '.delete', function () {
       var pageParamTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
        pageParamTable.row( tableRow ).remove().draw();
    });
});
```

I think this codes will help you.